# JNLP: getCodeBase() method from BasicService API does not return the complete codebase path

Tags: java, javafx-2, jnlp

My application's setup is like this:

I have a web page,  hosted on a server, that has a link to dynamically create a JNLP file that is rendered over http to the user. The JNLP is then used to launch a JavaFX application.

I need to access `getCodeBase()` method from the `BasicService` API to save a property locally on each user's machine. My JNLP that is created is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://myserver.com/downloads">
  <information>
    <title>My App</title>
    <vendor>My Vendor</vendor>
    <description>Application to do something</description>
    <homepage href="http://myserver.com/myapp" />
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut online="true">
      <desktop/>
      <menu submenu="My App"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>

  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
<update check="always"/>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7.0_25+" java-vm-args="-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"    href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <property name="myID" value="1" /> 
  </resources>

  <resources>
    <jar href="my-app-0.0.1.jar" download="eager" />
  </resources>

  <application-desc main-class="com.myApp.MyApp"/>

</jnlp>
```

The `getCodeBase()` method returns just `/downloads` rather than `http://myserver.com/downloads`. If anyone has any pointers to correct the error, those would be helpful.

The code I am using to access the codebase is below:

```
 try
    {
        persistenceService = (PersistenceService) ServiceManager
            .lookup("javax.jnlp.PersistenceService");
        basicService = (BasicService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
    }
    catch (UnavailableServiceException e)
    {
        persistenceService = null;
        basicService = null;
    }

    if (persistenceService != null
        && basicService != null)
    {

        try
        {
            URL codebase = basicService.getCodeBase();

            System.out.println("code base:" + codebase.getFile() + " path is : " + codebase.getPath());

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you call [getHostServices().getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#getCodeBase%28%29) in your JavaFX application?  That javadoc for that method states: "If the application was launched via a JNLP file, this method returns the codebase parameter specified in the JNLP file", which seems like it should comply with your `http://myserver.com/downloads` address.

Comment: Strangely, _`getHostServices().getCodeBase()`_ returns an empty string.